# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Белая душа, и так много ран"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Белая душа, и так много ран.

Нужна ли запятая в этом предложении после "и"?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна. Если запятую поставить, следует изменить союз "и" на союз "а". Тогда будет правильно: *"Белая душа, а так много ран"*.
Однако, по-моему, лучше поставить тире. Пример: *Милая женщина — и такая несчастная*. Здесь "и" выступает в роли "а", противительного союза. "Белая душа — и так много ран".
Если поставить просто запятую, происходит "соединительный" смысл союза "и", а нужно  противопоставление.
Еще примеры:
Собака — и такая умница. Учился, учился — и не поступил. Весна — и какая  дубарина! Нежно, мило — и  так бестолково!

Заметьте, что в Вашем случае еще и восклицательный знак просится для выражения эмоциональной окраски сожаления, сетования.

Comment: Непонятно, почему же не нужна запятая?

Comment: Ответ "запятая не нужна" вводит читателя в заблуждение: получается, что в этом предложении можно обойтись без знаков препинания, а это не так.

Comment: Я думаю, автор ответа хотел сказать, что нужно ставить не запятую, а тире, а не то, что можно обойтись без знаков препинания вообще.

Comment: Цитирую из первого ответа:
Здесь "и" выступает в роли "а", противительного союза. Абсолютно верно.
Цитирую оттуда же вывод:
Не нужна. Если запятую поставить, следует изменить союз "и" на союз "а". С этим абсолютно не согласен - по причине роли, которую "и" на себя взяло, этот союз получает предшествующую запятую. А то, что перед ним запятой быть не может (поскольку ОБЫЧНО это соединительный формант) - священной коровой не является.
Впрочем, постараюсь быть менее категоричным - наше разногласие в том, что является определяющим - оперативно выполняемая функция или же обычно выполняемая, другими

Comment: Затрудняете понимание Вашего текста отступлениями. Не цитируйте другие ответы (при том, что Ваш — не наблюдается), избегайте как минимум, оставляя дискуссии в комментариях. Цитируя, следуйте общим правилам выделения текста.

Answer (score 1):

**Белая душа, и так много ран.**

Союз И – не только соединительный (запятая не ставится), он может быть **противительным** и присоединительным (запятая ставится, пауза делается).

Из словаря:

Союз И. 4. Соединяет предложения и члены предложения, представляющие собой **противопоставляемые высказывания**.  Всё было уже готово, и всё-таки медлили начинать. * **Хотел объехать целый свет, И не объехал сотой доли** (Грибоедов).

Что мы получим без запятой? Однородные назывные предложения вида "Мороз и солнце"? Но здесь не соединение, а противопоставление, а в этом случае **пауза и запятая необходимы.**

Comment: С точки зрения синтаксиса "Мороз и солнце", “Белая душа, и так много ран” — это простые предложения или ССП?

Comment: Это ССП. У Розенталя  тема разбирается в этом  разделе: 6) односоставные номинативные (или назывные) предложения: Мороз и солнце…http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна перед "и". Это ССП с союзом "и". После "и" запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна. Она разделяет две фразы, которые можно записать отдельным предложением без потери смысла.